# Is detecting an impersonation by behaviour rolled vs. Disguise or Bluff?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, disguise

Another question pertaining to my Kitsune player. I've always disliked kitsune so it might be my own prejudices.

My Kitsune murdered someone and took their form and disguised himself from the group. The group had just been talking to the guy right before. 
So when they went to talk to the disguised kitsune they asked if it would be a bluff check instead of disguise because they aren't trying to look past looks, they are trying to look at mannerisms, since they know the kitsune and can tell that the guy they were just talking to is now acting completely different and the kitsune has disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Impersonation is handled by Disguise

This can be found on the [Disguise](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/disguise) skill description:

> If you are impersonating a particular individual, those who know what that person looks like get a bonus on their Perception checks according to the table below. Furthermore, they are automatically considered to be suspicious of you, so opposed checks are always called for.

[image]

Just take note of wether he is using [Realistic Likeness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/realistic-likeness-kitsune/) (+10) or another ability, as he might have a high bonus on his Disguise checks.

### But lies are handled by Bluff

But once you tricked the target, you are safe for at least an *hour*:

> Usually, an individual makes a Perception check to **see through your disguise immediately upon meeting you and every hour** thereafter. If you casually meet many different creatures, each for a short time, check once per day or hour, using an average Perception modifier for the group.

So for the duration of that *trickery*, you can freely make your Bluff checks at the target that they will still believe in your disguise. If you fail your Bluff check, maybe they will believe that the character is lying and get angry, but they will still believe in your disguise.